# Why aren't in loop variables duplicate, since they're decalred multiple times whwn within a loop?

Tags: java

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            int number;
            number=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Number you entered is : "+number);
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

The above code is just an example which prints the number you enter! (n number of times). The question is why don't I get a runtime error saying that the variable number is already declared and there's duplicate declaration?

Comment: Because each iteration has its own scope, so each iteration has a fresh scope.

Comment: Besides that kind of thing is checked at compile time, not runtime. There are no variable names at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration of the loop has a separate scope, so it is equivalent to writing:

```
{
    int number;
    number=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Number you entered is : "+number);
}
{
    int number;
    number=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Number you entered is : "+number);
}
...
{
    int number;
    number=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Number you entered is : "+number);
}
```

`n` times

Comment: This isn't really a correct use of the word "scope"; scope in Java (like in most languages) is lexical, so it's a static property of the code, not something that is determined at runtime. The variable has a different "lifetime" on each iteration of the loop.